# I can't display nested route in different view

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I've been trying to display a component in a different view from the parent component but what I get is the two components displayed in the same view, first parent component, and right below, child component when the `Link` is clicked.

It's a simple shopping cart (`/cart`) and after clicking `Pay` you should be redirected to checkout (`/cart/checkout`) view, nevertheless the `component` is being rendered right below.

I tried to set it up as a different route but the `component` `CheckoutData` won't render unless I nest into its `parent` `Cart.js`

I want to achieve this:

`Cart` component is rendered, after clicking `Pay` `Link` you should be redirected to `CheckoutData` component.

`Cart.js`

```
class Cart extends Component {
    // constructor and state

    removeItem(id) {
        // Axios call
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        //Axios call
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <ParentNav />
                // content table
                        <Link to="/cart/checkout">
                            Pay
                        </Link>

                        <Link to="/">
                            Go back
                        </Link>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <Footer />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

`CheckoutData.js`

```
class CheckoutData extends Component {
    //constructor and state

    render () {
        return (
        <div>
            <ParentNav />
            <CheckoutForm  passToken={this.state.token} />
            <Footer />
        </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Finally `Home.js` where the routed are declared

```
class Home extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <HashRouter>
                    <Switch>
                        <Route exact path="/">
                            <App />
                        </Route>
                        <Route path="/cart">
                            <Cart />
                            <Route path="/cart/checkout"  exact component={CheckoutData}/>
                        </Route>
                        <Route
                            path="/product/:id"
                            children={<SingleProduct />}
                        />
                    </Switch>
                </HashRouter>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: You should have another component for "/cart" and then you should declare route using Switch. To have Route for ```path={`${basePath}/`}``` and ```path={`${basePath}/checkout`}```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issue

You've nested a route within a route

```
<Route path="/cart">
  <Cart />
  <Route path="/cart/checkout" exact component={CheckoutData}/>
</Route>
```

The route path "/cart" is a prefix that will match any "/pathXXXXX" path, including "/cart/checkout". This means when any route's path includes "/cart" that those routes will be matched and rendered. The `Switch` matches and renders *the first* match.

> I tried to set it up as a different route but the component
> `CheckoutData` won't render unless I nest into its parent `Cart.js`.

The reason for this is likely because of the *order* in which you've defined the routes. If you did something like the following:

```
<Switch>
  <Route path="/cart">
    <Cart />
  </Route>
  <Route path="/cart/checkout" exact component={CheckoutData}/>
<Switch>
```

Then `<Route path="/cart">` will always match first and render, no matter what the rest of the path may be.

## Solution

Reorder your routes to define *more* specific paths before *less* specific paths. The alternative is to append the `exact` prop to *every* `Route`, which is both not very **DRY**, but also tedious and mundane.

```
<Switch>
  <Route
    path="/cart/checkout"       // <-- more specific path
    component={CheckoutData}/>
  <Route path="/cart">          // <-- less specific path
    <Cart />
  </Route>
  <Route
    path="/product/:id"
    children={<SingleProduct />}
  />
  <Route path="/">
    <App />
  </Route>
</Switch>
```

Comment: Hey Drew, coming from another framework like Laravel where routes are declared from general to specific I thank you for this. I will also have to be more carefull with the `exact` prop. Thanks for taking time to explain this.